# If $C$ is convex , weakly-closed and norm-bounded $\Longrightarrow$ $C$ is weakly-compact

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $C\subset X$.

$\fbox{1}$ If $C$ is convex , *weakly*-closed and *norm*-bounded $\Longrightarrow$ $C$ is *weakly*-compact ?

$\fbox{2}$ If $C$ is convex , *weakly*-closed   $\Longrightarrow$ $C$ is *weakly*-compact ?

Anyone knows a book where can study weak-weak*-topology  in Banach spaces ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I always suggest _Functional Analysis_ by Lax for these things.

Comment: Are you assuming that $X$ is reflexive?  If not, then (1) is false (and hence (2) is also false).

Comment: @felipeuni : Do you know that convex sets are closed if and only if they are weak-closed?

Comment: Let $X$ be a reflexive Banach space. Any closed convex bounded set is weakly compact.