# Compactness of unit ball in WOT of B(X)

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory

It is known that the unit ball in $\mathcal{B}(H)$, where $H$ is a separable Hilbert space is compact in the weak operator topology. Is it the same true if instead of $H$ we have any separable Banach space?

Comment: See also Theorem 2.19 here. http://www.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/thesis_file/14_J07-146.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It holds if and only if $X$ is reflexive.

First, note by [Equivalence of reflexive and weakly compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/199478/822) that $X$ is reflexive iff $\newcommand{\ball}{\operatorname{ball}}\ball X$ is weakly compact.

Suppose $X$ is not reflexive, so that $\ball X$ is not weakly compact.  Choose an arbitrary $h \in X$ with $\|h\| = 1$.  By the Hahn-Banach theorem there exists $\ell \in X^*$ with $\|\ell\|=1$ and $\ell(h) = 1$.  Then define $F : (B(X), \mathrm{WOT}) \to (X, \mathrm{wk})$ by $F(T) = Th$ which, by definition of WOT, is continuous.  To see it maps $\ball B(X)$ onto $\ball X$: given $f \in \ball X$, define $T_f$ by $T_f g = \ell(g) f$, so that $\|T_f\| = \|\ell\| \|f\| \le 1$ and $T_f h = f$.  So $F$ maps $(\ball B(X), \mathrm{WOT})$ continuously onto a non-compact set.

For the converse, suppose $X$ is reflexive so that $\ball X$ is weakly compact.  We mimic the proof of Alaoglu's theorem.  Let $K = (\ball X, \mathrm{wk})^{\ball X}$ with its product topology, which is compact by Tychonoff.  Then there is an obvious injection of $(\ball B(X), \mathrm{WOT})$ into $K$, which by definition of WOT is a homeomorphism onto its image.  If we show $\ball B(X)$ is closed in $K$, we will be done.  Let $T_\alpha$ be a net in $\ball B(X)$ and suppose it converges in $K$ (i.e. pointwise) to some function $T : \ball X \to \ball X$.  By scaling, we extend $T$ to a function $T : X \to X$.  It's easy to check that $T$ is linear.  To see that $T$ is bounded, note that if $f \in \ball X$ we have $T_\alpha f \to Tf$ weakly.  Since the [Norm is weakly lower semicontinuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/470217/norm-is-weakly-lower-semicontinuous) we get $\|Tf\| \le \liminf \|T_\alpha f\| \le 1$.  So indeed $T \in \ball B(X)$, showing that $\ball B(X)$ is closed in $K$, hence WOT-compact.

---

For a concrete counterexample, let $X = C([0,1])$ and consider the evaluation map $F : (B(X), \mathrm{WOT}) \to (X, \mathrm{wk})$ defined by $F(T) = T1$ where $1 \in C([0,1])$ is the constant function 1.  It's easy to check $F$ is continuous (this is basically the definition of WOT).  Moreover, I claim we have $F(\ball B(X)) = \ball X$; given $f \in \ball X$, define $T \in B(X)$ by $Tg(x) = g(0) f(x)$.  Clearly $\|T\| = \|f\| \le 1$ and $T1 = f$.  Hence if $\ball B(X)$ is WOT compact then $\ball X$ must be weakly compact.

In this case we can see explicitly that $\ball X$ is not weakly compact.  Let $f_n(x) = x^n$; I claim this sequence has no weak-* accumulation point.    Since $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise and point evaluation is a continuous linear functional on $C([0,1])$, any weak accumulation point of $f_n$ must equal the pointwise limit.  But the pointwise limit is not continuous so no such accumulation point can exist.

Comment: Thank you. You answer seem to indicate this is true when $X$  is reflexive, right?

Comment: @Markus: I don't know whether it is true for all reflexive $X$.

Comment: Perhaps I will ask a separate question. Intuitively, I feel it is true if $X$ has a Schauder basis $(e_j)$. The biorthogonal functionals are a basis of the dual, and the proof should be similar with the one for $B(H)$.

Comment: @Markus: Actually, I think I can prove it holds for reflexive $X$.  Let me write it.

Comment: I posted a separate question, perhaps post your answer there. Thanks again!

Comment: @Markus: Oops, I didn't see your comment and posted it here anyway.  Maybe it is best to keep it here and mark the other question as duplicate.