# Unit ball of $X^{**}$ is weakly compact!

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Is it true that the closed unit ball in $X^{**}$ is compact with respect to the weak topology on $X^{**}$, where $X$ is a Banach space? If so, how can we prove it?

Comment: "Closed unit ball of $Y^*$ is compact in weak topology for any Banach space". I don't think this is true

Comment: @mathworker21 This is true for the weak$^*$-topology, not the weak topology.

Comment: my apologies you guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unit ball of any Banach space $X$ is compact with respect to the weak topology if and only if $X$ is reflexive (a good exercise, which I recommend trying).  Since a Banach space is reflexive if and only if $X^*$ is reflexive, we have

> If $X$ is a Banach space, then the unit ball of $X^{**}$ is weakly compact if and only if $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: Thank you @Aweygan . Will certainly try that exercise.

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

It is not true in general. The unit ball in an arbitrary Banach space is weakly compact if and only this Banach space is reflexive (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199478/equivalence-of-reflexive-and-weakly-compact) for references and a proof sketch). The second dual of a Banach space is not necessarily reflexive; in fact, the dual of a Banach space is reflexive if and only if the Banach space itself is reflexive (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152343/a-banach-space-is-reflexive-if-and-only-if-its-dual-is-reflexive)). Thus, the unit ball in $Y^{\ast\ast}$ is weakly compact if and only if $Y$ is reflexive.